# Toggle Bing Maps Dashboard

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

Is there any way to toggle the bing maps dashboard('showDashboard' option) using the api v7?

I know that it can be set in the constructor, but I want to be able to show/hide this dashboard after the map is rendered and i dont want to recreate the map every time a user wants to show or hide the controlls.

I tried using:

```
map.setOptions({showDashboard : userOption})
```

but it doesnt work.

In the documentation it states that "[This property can only be set when using the Map constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427603.aspx).", but I'm still hoping for a solution/hack....even tho i've been searching for a solution all over the internet.

Thanks in advance.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up recreating the map on each show/hide action and it seems to work ok, but it would have been nice if there was a way of doing this without having to destroy and render the map again....i know for a fact that this can be done in gmaps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannon achieve this through API.
The best solution is to control this manually after the maps loaded

Just use

$(".MicrosoftNav").style.visibility = "hidden" // To hide the nav bar

Or

$(".MicrosoftNav").style.visibility = "visible" // To show the nav bar

I suppose the bing will not change the class of "MicrosoftNav", but who knows...

Comment: This is not a good solution for me because i can never know if that class will be changed or not. I ended up recreating the map on each show/hide action.Thanks for the reply tho.